# Why Does Array Assignment in Controller Break Angular Code?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, binding

This is more of a conceptual question. I have the following HTML page:

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

    <head>
        <title>Angular Page</title>
        <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="app.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div ng-controller="myController">
            {{ greeting }}
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

With all files **at the root of the directory**, I also have the following JS file:

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myController', function($scope) {
    $scope.greeting = "Hello";
}
```

When this runs, I of course receive the greeting "Hello" on the HTML page.

However, when I attempt to append an object (for a future ng-repeat element) to the same controller:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myController', function($scope) {
    $scope.greeting = "Hello";

    $scope.users = [
        {
            "name": "Michael",
            "industry": "Music"
        },
        {
            "name": "Michael",
            "industry": "Boxing"
        },
        {
            "name": "Michael",
            "industry": "Basketball"
        }
    ];
}
```

The Angular binding is broken, and instead of the greeting "Hello", I receive the {{ name }} expression. (This is with or without the trailing semi-colon on the 'users' object assignment.)

Is there something about my object assignment that caused a break in my Angular code? I wouldn't be exactly sure how to explain what happened.

Comment: Read the error in console explaining what is wrong.

Comment: does the {{ name }} expression change to "Hello", after a few seconds or does it stay there whole time?

Comment: @dfsq Can't believe I hadn't done that. This is what happens when you're editing your JS files using the SSH. There was a spelling error that I wasn't catching on the black and green screen. Kudos! Please resubmit to be credited for answer. Salutations...

Comment: @TimCodes it stays there the whole time. There was a comma instead of a colon on the actual object (too sensitive to be pasted on a public board). Had I been using an actual GUI instead of Nano, I would have caught it myself. Two hours of insanity before posting the problem here. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@dfsq is off somewhere helping others, so he couldn't properly receive credit for answering this question.

The issue was after inserting an array object into my Angular 'myController', the two-way binding was broken for the expression on the page.

I was using nano from the command line (SSH) on the server to edit the file and could not easily see that one of the key value pairs in the array

```
("key": "value")
```

had a comma instead of a colon

```
("key","value)
```

so it was throwing the following error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ,
```

The issue was, I could have used the developer tools on my browser to check the console log. @dfsq suggested this, and after viewing the console log, it was easy to see the error thrown and exactly which line was throwing it.

Thanks again, @dfsq